Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string' - React Native
I just installed this DropDownPicker UI component in React Native (source: https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/usage).
Here's the code:
  const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Daily', value: 'Daily'},
    {label: 'Weekly', value: 'Weekly'},
    {label: 'BiWeekly', value: 'BiWeekly'},
    {label: 'Monthly', value: 'Monthly'},
  ]);

....blah blah blah....

    <DropDownPicker
            open={open}
            value={value}
            items={items}
            setOpen={setOpen}
            setValue={setValue}
            setItems={setItems}
            onChangeValue={(value) => {
              console.log(value);
              setFrequency(value);
              console.log(frequency);
            }}
            style={{marginLeft:10,width:'90%', marginBottom:10}}
      />

Intellisense complains on the line where I am trying to call setFrequency(value) with the error mentioned in the Title of this question. I need to set the value of frequency to the value selected in the DropDownPicker. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

This means that onChangeValue must be a callable with (value: string | null) => void signature. Your arrow is inferred to that type, but your frequency is inferred to be a string. You should either allow storing null in frequency or do something with null inside that handler - it all depends on your business logic (what should happen if the value is not selected/cleared and during the initial call). You may want setFrequency(value ?? '') if you just want to use an empty string as a "no value" indicator.

As per the interface declaration of file https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/blob/5.x/index.d.ts of this DropDown Picker library
onChangeValue function can receive any generic type as well as null value in its argument.
Here you can simply use as below method to fix this Intellisense warning.
setFrequency(value as string);

